# sagepay curl request

Tags: php, curl, payment-gateway, opayo

I want to process payments through my website and wanted to use sagepay for that purpose. I have gone through the guideline for sagepay go direct integration mentioned here:
http://www.sagepay.com/sites/default/files/pdf/user_guides/sagepaydirectprotocolandintegrationguidelines_0.pdf
Now,
I have created a script made necessary changes needed for the fields to process http request. here is the code:

```
<?php
//extract data from the post
extract($_POST);

//set POST variables
$url = 'https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspdirect-register.vsp';
$txcode = 'prefix_' . time() . rand(0, 9999);
$fields = array(
                        'VPSProtocol'=>urlencode("2.23"),
                        'TxType'=>urlencode("PAYMENT"),
                        'Vendor'=>urlencode("myvendorname"),
                        'VendorTxCode'=>urlencode($txcode),
                        'Amount'=>urlencode("2.00"),
                        'Currency'=>urlencode("GBP"),
                        'Description'=>urlencode("payment for my site"),
                        'CardHolder'=>urlencode('DELTA'),
                        'CardNumber'=>urlencode(4929000000006),
                        'ExpiryDate'=>urlencode(1213),
                        'CV2'=>urlencode(123),
                        'CardType'=>urlencode('VISA'),
                        'BillingSurname'=>urlencode('surname'),
                        'BillingFirstnames'=>urlencode('name'),
                        'BillingAddress1'=>urlencode(' clifton'),
                        'BillingCity'=>urlencode('Bristol'),
                        'BillingPostCode'=>urlencode('BS82UE'),
                        'BillingCountry'=>urlencode('United Kingdom'),
                        'DeliverySurname'=>urlencode('surname'),
                        'DeliveryFirstnames'=>urlencode('name'),
                        'DeliveryAddress1'=>urlencode(' clifton'),
                        'DeliveryCity'=>urlencode('Bristol'),
                        'DeliveryPostCode'=>urlencode('bs82ue'),
                        'DeliveryCountry'=>urlencode('united kingdom'),

                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
echo "end";
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

But I am not getting any response back.. what could be the problem? Its in wamp server and non https url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me. I added a few CURL functions and removed one and that did the trick.

```
<?php
//extract data from the post
extract($_POST);

//set POST variables
$url = 'https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspdirect-register.vsp';
$txcode = 'prefix_' . time() . rand(0, 9999);
$fields = array(
                        'VPSProtocol'=>urlencode("2.23"),
                        'TxType'=>urlencode("PAYMENT"),
                        'Vendor'=>urlencode("myvendorname"),
                        'VendorTxCode'=>urlencode($txcode),
                        'Amount'=>urlencode("2.00"),
                        'Currency'=>urlencode("GBP"),
                        'Description'=>urlencode("payment for my site"),
                        'CardHolder'=>urlencode('DELTA'),
                        'CardNumber'=>urlencode(4111111111111111),
                        'ExpiryDate'=>urlencode(1213),
                        'CV2'=>urlencode(123),
                        'CardType'=>urlencode('VISA'),
                        'BillingSurname'=>urlencode('surname'),
                        'BillingFirstnames'=>urlencode('name'),
                        'BillingAddress1'=>urlencode(' clifton'),
                        'BillingCity'=>urlencode('Bristol'),
                        'BillingPostCode'=>urlencode('BS82UE'),
                        'BillingCountry'=>urlencode('United Kingdom'),
                        'DeliverySurname'=>urlencode('surname'),
                        'DeliveryFirstnames'=>urlencode('name'),
                        'DeliveryAddress1'=>urlencode(' clifton'),
                        'DeliveryCity'=>urlencode('Bristol'),
                        'DeliveryPostCode'=>urlencode('bs82ue'),
                        'DeliveryCountry'=>urlencode('united kingdom'),

                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
echo "end";
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

FYI, using [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) is great for building query_strings.

```
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work if you add field

```
Crypt='Your encryption password in your account setting in sagepay test';
```

But it returns null string if you use curl to post and it will be redirected to

```
https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/cardselection?vpstxid={BDBF098F-9BB5-3822-8CAE-AC0645A2CC57}
```

if you use Http POST.

Goodluck